# Labelling Neo4j database using Neo4django

Tags: groovy, label, neo4django

This question is related to the [github issue](https://github.com/scholrly/neo4django/issues/155) of Neo4django. I want to create multiple graphs using Neo4j graph DB from Django web framework. I'm using Django 1.4.5, neo4j 1.9.2 and neo4django 0.1.8.

As of now Neo4django doesn't support labeling but the above is my core purpose and I want to be able to create labels from Neo4django. So I went into the source code and tried to tweak it a little to see if I can make this addition. In my understanding, the file 'db/models/properties.py' has class BoundProperty(AttrRouter) which calls gremlin script through function *save*(instance, node, node_is_new). The script is as follows:

```
script = '''
    node=g.v(nodeId);
    results = Neo4Django.updateNodeProperties(node, propMap);
    '''
```

The script calls the update function from library.groovy and all the function looks intuitive and nice. I'm trying to add on this function to support labeling but I have no experience of groovy. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed? Any help would be appreciated. If it works it would be a big addition to neo4django :)

Thank you

Comment: Are you planning to switch to Neo4j 2.0M03? 1.9.2 doesn't support labels.

Comment: I upgraded to Neo4j 2.0M03 for experimenting purposes. Hopefully by the time our product is ready for production the stable version 2.0 will be out. Thank you for the pointers :)

Comment: I've just launched a campaign to fund the next release of the library- labels are in the list of stretch goals. Check it out https://www.bountysource.com/fundraisers/423-neo4django-0-1-9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little background:

The Groovy code you've highlighted is executed using the Neo4j Gremlin plugin. First it supports the [Gremlin graph DSL](https://github.com/tinkerpop/gremlin) (eg `node=g.v(nodeId)`), which is implemented atop the Groovy language. Groovy itself is a dynamic superset of Java, so most valid Java code will work with scripts sent via `connection.gremlin(...)`. Each script sent should define a `results` variable that will be returned to neo4django, even if it's just `null`.

Anyway, accessing Neo4j this way is handy (though will be deprecated I've heard :( ) because you can use the full [Neo4j embeddeded Java API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.0.0-M03/tutorials-java-embedded.html). Try something like this to add a label to a node

```
from neo4django.db import connection
connection.gremlin("""
node = g.v(nodeId)
label = DynamicLabel.label('Label_Name')
node.rawVertex.addLabel(label)
""", nodeId=node_id)
```

You might also need to add an import for `DynamicLabel`- I haven't run this code so I'm not sure. Debugging code written this way is a little tough, so make liberal use of the Gremlin tab in the Neo4j admin.

If you come up with a working solution, I'd love to see it (or an explanatory blog post!)- I'm sure it could be helpful to other users.

HTH!

NB - Labels will be properly supported shortly after Neo4j 2.0's release- they'll replace the current in-graph type structure.